# Crystal Reports: Is it possible to sum for more than one column?

Tags: crystal-reports, sum

I work on an accounting project in .NET.
I want to sum all transaction and its opening balances.
I use summary but it Allows only one column..

Comment: Why don't you accept your answers!? There is a V place near each answer, you should mark as answer if the post answered your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can summarize within formulas, so long as the formula field is present in the report footer.  When using `Sum()` CR knows to evaluate the expression for all records returned.

So you would create a formula for the report footer, and the formula code would be something like:

```
Sum({@TransactionAmt1}) + Sum({Transactions.Amount}) + Sum({@AnotherFormula});
```